# Reading lines from a non-blocking reader

Tags: c++

I want to read `\n` terminated, UTF-8 encoded lines from a network connection and process each full line. I cannot use `fgets`, because that function does not support nonblocking IO, which I want to use.

I currently have the following code, but it looks a bit too confusing to me. Some tips on how to simplify the code would be appreciated.

```
#include <array>
#include <string.h>

// Read lines from a non-blocking reader (e.g. an O_NONBLOCK socket).
// Every complete line is sent to a consumer function, without a newline or null terminator.
// Lines larger than BufSize are silently discarded.
//
// Reader should have approximately this signature:
//   ssize_t reader(void *buffer, size_t maxSize);
//   Should return 0 on EOF, -1 on error, otherwise the number of read bytes.
//   In practice, this should just call read() on a file descriptor.
// Consumer should have approximately this signature:
//   void consumer(const char *start, size_t size);
template<size_t BufSize>
class LineBuffer {
    std::array<char, BufSize> _buffer;
    size_t _bytesBuffered {0};
    size_t _bytesConsumed {0};
    bool _discardLine {false};
public:
    template<typename Reader, typename Consumer>
    size_t readLines(const Reader& reader, const Consumer& consumer)
    {
        char *buf = _buffer.data();
        while (true) {
            auto bytesRead = reader(buf + _bytesBuffered, _buffer.size() - _bytesBuffered);
            if (bytesRead <= 0) {
                return bytesRead;
            }
            _bytesBuffered += bytesRead;

            char* separator = nullptr;
            do {
                char* lineStart = buf + _bytesConsumed;
                separator = static_cast<char*>(memchr(
                    lineStart,
                    '\n',
                    _bytesBuffered - _bytesConsumed));

                if (separator) {
                    size_t lineLength = separator - lineStart;
                    if (!_discardLine) {
                        consumer(lineStart, lineLength);
                    }
                    _bytesConsumed += lineLength + 1;
                    _discardLine = false;
                }
            } while (separator);
            resetBuffer();
        }
    }
private:
    void resetBuffer() {
        size_t bytesRemaining = _bytesBuffered - _bytesConsumed;
        if (bytesRemaining == _buffer.size()) {
            // line too long
            _discardLine = true;
            _bytesBuffered = 0;
            _bytesConsumed = 0;
        } else if (bytesRemaining > 0 && _bytesConsumed > 0) {
            // move the last partial message to the front of the buffer, so a full-sized
            // message will fit
            memmove(_buffer.data(), _buffer.data() + _bytesConsumed, bytesRemaining);
            _bytesBuffered = bytesRemaining;
            _bytesConsumed = 0;
        }
    }
};

// Small test
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

LineBuffer<16> buffer;
void feed(const char *testData) {
    auto end = testData + strlen(testData);
    buffer.readLines(
        [&](void *buf, size_t maxSize) {
            auto size = std::min((ssize_t) maxSize, end - testData);
            memcpy(buf, testData, size);
            testData += size;
            return size;
        },
        [](const char *line, size_t size) {
            std::cout << std::string {line, size} << std::endl;
        });
}

int main() {
    // expected output: one, two, three, four, five, 0123456789abcde.
    feed("one\ntwo\n");
    feed("thr");
    feed("ee\n");
    feed("four\nThis line should be discarded, because it is too long.\n");
    feed("five\n0123456789abcde\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
           if (bytesRead <= 0) {
                return bytesRead;
            }
```

How can an unsigned type be less than zero?

```
static_cast<char*>(memchr(
```

Why aren't you using std algorithms?  You want to find the '\n' character in the text, right?  That just `std::find(begin_iterator, end_iterator, '\n')`.  No casting.

```
memmove(_buffer.data(), _buffer.data() + _bytesConsumed, bytesRemaining);
```

again, use `std::copy` or `copy_n`, not `memmove`.

For whatever functions you do use, include the proper headers for them.  I see you have `<string.h>` but you should not use the C headers in C++.  Use `<cstring>` instead.

[⧺SL.io.50](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#slio50-avoid-endl) Don't use `endl`.

If you are expecting this to be launched using `async` or similar, and it runs until the stream is closed or errored or whatever, then returning a value is not very useful: who are you returning it to?  As noted earlier, it will *always* return 0, so it's useless to have this return value.

---

I don't understand how your loop works.

```
do {
  // read stuff
  if (separator) { ... }
while (separator);
```

I thought it would keep reading until it found the end-of-line, but this keeps looping until it *doesn't* read something with a linebreak.

I agree it's complex, because of your looping and condition structure.  You have state variables that need to be understood in order to understand the flow.  It could be written in a simpler way as a single loop with clearer conditions.

Comment: As I understand it from the comments at the start of the program, `auto bytesRead = reader(...)` is expected to return a `ssize_t` which is a signed type and can be negative.

Comment: So the return type of readLines should match that, since it's the only return statement.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. (It was not apparent to me if your point is about the signed-ness of  `bytesRead` or about the signed-ness of the return type of the function.)